# Show Top % of the month in the Android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app

If your profile says top 3% of the month, for example, it would be nice to see that in your profile in the app. In addition, when the user clicks on that, to bring you to the leaderboard, like the existing one on the website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The android app is deprecated, so this is no longer feasible.